# Automatic locale detection in a xulrunner app

Tags: xulrunner

I have an xulrunner app which has Japanese and English locales. Using `-UILocale <locale>` to switch locales works fine, so there's no problem with the actual locale files or code, but running the app on Japanese computers, it still comes up in English. Apparently ["normally the application locale is inherited from the OS environment of the host system"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_enable_locale_switching_in_a_XULRunner_application), but that doesn't seem to be happening on Windows or OS X.

I have added the default `pref("intl.locale.matchOS", "true")` just to be sure, but still no dice. I've also tried pretty much every version of xulrunner.

*How* is xulrunner supposed to detect the system locale, and how can I make it do so?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Make_your_xulrunner_app_match_the_system_locale

```
from xpcom import components
ps_cls = components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
ps = ps_cls.getService(components.interfaces.nsIPrefService)
branch = ps.getBranch("general.useragent.")
branch.setCharPref("locale", lang)

os.environ["LANGUAGE"] = lang
```

set lang as per locale.

Comment: The documentation (which of course I have read) isn't useful since it assumes that I'm using Python, which I'm not. (Nor are most users of XUL.)